# Flutter : Save List<dynamic> to SharedPreferences from Json.encode

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to save AppInfo information from API into SharedPreferences. I have **source code** and **result JSON** like this :

APP_INFO_API.dart:

```
  Future<List> getAppInfo() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
          "${appConfig.baseApiUrl}/${appConfig.appInfoController}/getLogoClient");
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseJson["status"] == "ok") {
        List appInfoList = responseJson["data"];
print('List Dynamic From API : $appInfoList ');
        return appInfoList;
      } else {
        throw CustomError(responseJson["message"]);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

### Result JSON

```
 List Dynamic From API : [{kodeInfo: 1, namaInfo: Integrasi Operasional Outlet, keteranganInfo: Burger Klenger ERPOS Version 1.2, fileInfo: img-1.png, logoInfo: logo-1.png, loginBackgroundInfo: bfront-1.png, loginLeftInfo: bleft-1.png, loginSupportInfo: bsupport-1.png, createBy: , createTime: 0000-00-00 00:00:00, updateBy: hambaallah, updateTime: 2020-02-09 06:32:57}]
```

I already read the documentation about type data that can be store in `SharedPreferences`, and I found can be store as `List[String]`. The problem is return of **appInfoList** above is `List[dynamic]`, It's possible convert from `List[dynamic]` to  `List[String]`, so i can add it to `SharedPreferences` ?

## My Experiment

I follow This [Link](https://github.com/afgprogrammer/flutter_expense_manager/blob/master/lib/Providers/CardProvider.dart) and try to implement it.

I create `GlobalProvider` To Store Value From API.

```
class GlobalProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  static const _APP_INFO_LIST123 = "appInfoList123";

  GlobalProvider() {
    syncDataWithProvider();
  }

 List<AppInfoModel> appInfoList123 = [];  


   Future updateSharedPreferencesAppInfo123(List<dynamic> value) async {
    List<String> myAppInfoList123 = value.map((e) => json.encode(e)).toList();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final result =
        await prefs.setStringList(_APP_INFO_LIST123, myAppInfoList123);
    print('result from updateSP $result');
    print('Myappinfolist123 : $myAppInfoList123');
  }

  Future syncDataWithProvider() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var result = prefs.getStringList(_APP_INFO_LIST123);
    print('The Result is $result');
    if (result != null) {
      appInfoList123 = result
          .map<AppInfoModel>((e) => AppInfoModel.fromJson(json.decode(e)))
          .toList();
    }
    print('Hore $appInfoList123');
    notifyListeners();
  }


}
```

Then, when I access it like this :

### SplashScreen.dart

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  GlobalProvider globalProvider;
 @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    globalProvider = Provider.of<GlobalProvider>(context);
    testing(globalProvider);
  }

  testing(GlobalProvider gp) async {
    final appInfoList = appInfoApi.getAppInfo();
    final result = await appInfoList;
    print('Hello List Dynamic From didChangeDependecies : $result');
    return await gp.updateSharedPreferencesAppInfo123(result);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text(globalProvider.appInfoList123[0].fileInfo)), <!!! IN HERE
    );
}

}
```

But i got this error

### Error

[image]

```
I/flutter (26131): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (26131): The following RangeError was thrown building SplashScreen(dirty, dependencies:
I/flutter (26131): [_DefaultInheritedProviderScope<GlobalProvider>], state: _SplashScreenState#a10e3):
I/flutter (26131): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
I/flutter (26131):
I/flutter (26131): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (26131):   SplashScreen 
lib\main.dart:42
I/flutter (26131):
I/flutter (26131): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (26131): #0      List.[]  (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:146:60)
I/flutter (26131): #1      _SplashScreenState.build 
package:klenger_burger_app/screens/splash_screen.dart:88
I/flutter (26131): #2      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4590
I/flutter (26131): #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4478
I/flutter (26131): #4      StatefulElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4646
I/flutter (26131): #5      Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4202
I/flutter (26131): #6      ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4461
I/flutter (26131): #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4637
I/flutter (26131): #8      ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4456
I/flutter (26131): ...     Normal element mounting (115 frames)
I/flutter (26131): #123    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3430
I/flutter (26131): #124    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5857
I/flutter (26131): ...     Normal element mounting (253 frames)
I/flutter (26131): #377    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3430
I/flutter (26131): #378    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3198
I/flutter (26131): #379    ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4498
I/flutter (26131): #380    _InheritedProviderScopeMixin.performRebuild 
package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:220
I/flutter (26131): #381    Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4202
I/flutter (26131): #382    ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4461
I/flutter (26131): #383    ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4456
I/flutter (26131): ...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
I/flutter (26131): #390    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount 
package:nested/nested.dart:223
I/flutter (26131): ...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
I/flutter (26131): #397    _NestedHookElement.mount 
package:nested/nested.dart:188
I/flutter (26131): ...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
I/flutter (26131): #404    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount 
package:nested/nested.dart:223
I/flutter (26131): #405    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3430
I/flutter (26131): #406    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3198
I/flutter (26131): #407    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1142
I/flutter (26131): #408    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1113
I/flutter (26131): #409    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1055
I/flutter (26131): #410    BuildOwner.buildScope 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2591
I/flutter (26131): #411    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1054
I/flutter (26131): #412    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget 

package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:935
I/flutter (26131): #413    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:917
I/flutter (26131): (elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
I/flutter (26131):
I/flutter (26131): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Any recommendation how can i adding `List[dynamic]` into `SharedPreferences` ?

#### If you need My Model

```
class AppInfoModel {
  String kodeInfo;
  String namaInfo;
  String keteranganInfo;
  String fileInfo;
  String logoInfo;
  String loginBackgroundInfo;
  String loginLeftInfo;
  String loginSupportInfo;
  String createBy;
  String createTime;
  String updateBy;
  DateTime updateTime;

  AppInfoModel({
    this.kodeInfo,
    this.namaInfo,
    this.keteranganInfo,
    this.fileInfo,
    this.logoInfo,
    this.loginBackgroundInfo,
    this.loginLeftInfo,
    this.loginSupportInfo,
    this.createBy,
    this.createTime,
    this.updateBy,
    this.updateTime,
  });

  factory AppInfoModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AppInfoModel(
        kodeInfo: json["kodeInfo"] == null ? '' : json["kodeInfo"],
        namaInfo: json["namaInfo"] == null ? '' : json["namaInfo"],
        keteranganInfo:
            json["keteranganInfo"] == null ? '' : json["keteranganInfo"],
        fileInfo: json["fileInfo"] == null ? '' : json["fileInfo"],
        logoInfo: json["logoInfo"] == null ? '' : json["logoInfo"],
        loginBackgroundInfo: json["loginBackgroundInfo"] == null
            ? ''
            : json["loginBackgroundInfo"],
        loginLeftInfo:
            json["loginLeftInfo"] == null ? '' : json["loginLeftInfo"],
        loginSupportInfo:
            json["loginSupportInfo"] == null ? '' : json["loginSupportInfo"],
        createBy: json["createBy"] == null ? '' : json["createBy"],
        createTime: json["createTime"] == null ? '' : json["createTime"],
        updateBy: json["updateBy"] == null ? '' : json["updateBy"],
        updateTime: DateTime.parse(json["updateTime"]) == null
            ? ''
            : DateTime.parse(json["updateTime"]),
      );
  Map toJson() => {
        'kodeInfo': this.kodeInfo,
        'namaInfo': this.namaInfo,
        'keteranganInfo': this.keteranganInfo,
        'fileInfo': this.fileInfo,
        'logoInfo': this.logoInfo,
        'loginBackgroundInfo': this.loginBackgroundInfo,
        'loginLeftInfo': this.loginLeftInfo,
        'loginSupportInfo': this.loginSupportInfo,
        'createBy': this.createBy,
        'createTime': this.createTime,
        'updateBy': this.updateBy,
        'updateTime': this.updateTime,
      };
}

final appInfoModel = AppInfoModel();
```

Comment: Did you tried `json.encode`ing on writing and `json.deocde`ing when reading?

Comment: @MisirJafarov Yes, i already try that. The problem is , when i access it in **splashscreen** i get error like above, but strangely if i refresh again, error still show but the **value** show

Comment: fyi: unlike some languages dart json decoder converts json objects to map not directly to object. So you need to map each property to you own class.

Comment: @MisirJafarov in my **GlobalProvider** function **syncDataWithProvider** i already map each property. Correct Me If i Wrong.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did made a mistake. You need to use [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), [`ValieListenableBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) or something else to wait while the data is reading. Because `syncDataWithProvider` is asynchronous call. Which means it will not block current thread while execution is completed.

```dart
class GlobalProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  static const _APP_INFO_LIST123 = "appInfoList123";

  GlobalProvider() {
    future = syncDataWithProvider();
  }

 List<AppInfoModel> appInfoList123 = [];  
 Future future;

 Fure updateSharedPreferencesAppInfo123(List<dynamic> value) async {
   List<String> myAppInfoList123 = value.map((e) => json.encode(e)).toList();
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   final result = await prefs.setStringList(_APP_INFO_LIST123, myAppInfoList123);
   print('result from updateSP $result');
   print('Myappinfolist123 : $myAppInfoList123');
 }

 Future syncDataWithProvider() async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   var result = prefs.getStringList(_APP_INFO_LIST123);
   print('The Result is $result');
   if (result != null) {
     appInfoList123 = result
       .map<AppInfoModel>((e) => AppInfoModel.fromJson(json.decode(e)))
       .toList();
   }
   print('Hore $appInfoList123');
   notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And your view.dart

```dart
return FutureBuilder(
  future: globalProvider.future,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text('Loading...');
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(globalProvider.appInfoList123[0].fileInfo),
      ),
    )
  }
);
```